# validating a sql element exists in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

Hey guys I am trying to validate that a username exists in a database.  I am having an issue with checking it against the database to see if that username exists.  I have done some research and have no found that correct way to do it in mvc ( new to asp.net and mvc).  If anybody could just point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my validation method:

```
private bool isValid(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

                var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }

                return isValid;
        }
```

So far it lets anybody log in even if they aren't in the database.

Comment: Don't you want to check the password?

Comment: Yes, working on the username right now, but will need to do the password as well.  One step at a time for this guy ;)

Comment: FYI Where() will never return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, will mark as answer when timer is up.  Now to just match the password :).  Thank you for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just for explanation, without the `FirstOrDefault`, you always return an IEnumerable, sometimes with zero records, sometimes with 1, but never null.

Comment: You might consider using SingleOrDefault instead of FirstorDefault. It states the assumption of a single item in the db (so it's more readable) and checks for duplicates (an exception will be thrown if any), although might be a bit slower (it has to iterate through all items). Nevertheless I would recommend to use it instead.

Answer (score 2):

A much more terse method than what you are using would be to leverage off of the `.Any()` LINQ method.  This way, you don't need to keep track of an `IsValid` variable either.

```
private bool isValid(string UserName, string Password)
   {
        //returns true if there is any match, false if no match
        return db.User.Any(u=> u.UserName == UserName);   
   }
```

Also, if you actually want to retrieve the user to do other things to the User object, you can shortcut the `.Where()` and simply use `.FirstOrDefault()` in place of the where clause.

```
private bool isValid(string UserName, string Password)
   {
        var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(u=> u.UserName == UserName);
        //return true if user is not null, false if user is null   
        return user != null   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote validation:

**ValidationController:**

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class ValidationController : ControllerBaseNoAuthorize
{
    public JsonResult IsNameAlreadyInUse([Bind(Prefix = "User.Name")]string Name)
    {
        return NameAlreadyInUse(Name);
    }

    protected JsonResult NameAlreadyInUse(string name)
    {
        vvar user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);
        if (user == null)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class ModelRegistrationModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsNameAlreadyInUse", "Validation", areaName: "AreaName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```